# Accessing list elements with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to BS and trying to scrape a results page and access all the results from it which are kept in a list. I am able to access the ordered list that contains all the results, but unsure of how to iterate through all of them and pull all the info I need.

Here is the html for the page im scraping: [Page HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ki1o.jpg)

I am trying to grab the href title, href link, description, and data timestamp. The end result should be in a container that look like this: 
`{title: ['Disney plus account . - THIEF'], link: [/search/search/redirect?search_term=...], description: ['No description provided'], timestamp: ['June 26, 2023, 8:59 p.m.']}`

Here is my code for accessing the list:

```
result = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
ordered_list = soup.find_all('ol', class_ = 'searchResults')
```

Where should I go from here? How would I go about iterating and pulling info from each result? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Adding a hyperlink to an image of a partial HTML document isn't very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for printing the results, with conditional checks for each value if it exists. You can use a list or DataFrame to store the results if you want to save them for later on.

```
result = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
for list_element in soup.find('ol', class_ = 'searchResults').find_all('li'):
    print({
        'title': list_element.find('h4').text if list_element.find('h4') else '',
        'link': list_element.find('a').get('href') if list_element.find('a') else '',
        'description': list_element.find('p').text if list_element.find('p') else '',
        'timestamp': list_element.find('span', {'class': 'lastSeen'}).get('data-timestamp') if list_element.find('span', {'class': 'lastSeen'}) else '', 
    })
```